# Location of the phone when user clicks on a button

Tags: android, android-location

In my application I need to get the phone location once the user clicks on a button. Here is my code.

```
import android.location.*;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;
    private Button sendrequest;
    private TextView text;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private String provider;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setViews();
    }

    private void setViews() {
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        sendrequest = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        sendrequest.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
                provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
                Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
                if (location != null) {
                    text.append("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
                    //onLocationChanged(location);
                  } else {
                      text.append("Location not avilable");
                  }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

But Its not returning me the location. Its just appending the "Location not available" string to the text TextView. I know that it is because it is returning the last stored location which is null. But I dont want to use the LocationListener as I want the location only once. ie when user starts the app. Please help.

Comment: I'm guessing you're running this on an emulator. If so AFAIK it always returns null on the emulator. Have you tried it on an actual device ?

Comment: Yes. I did. Same result.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to set below permissions in your android manifest xml file to access location.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: @shrigurunayak follow this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/).

Comment: Thanks :). I have negated it by giving a + :P